# Return value or null, without null reference exception linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to return the category Name or just null within the projection below, but I get a null reference exception, which makes sense if result.CategoryId is null.

```
return results.Select(i =>
new Model
{
  Score = i.Score
 ,Date = i.InstanceResult.TestDate
 ,Category = categories.Where(c=>c.Id.Equals(i.result.CategoryId)).SingleOrDefault().Name
});
```

Comment: what's the type of categoryId

Comment: so don't use `c.Id.Equals(...)` use `c.Id == ...`

Comment: categoryId is int on in the categories list, but CategoryId is a nullable int in the result object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if there's a category with that Id then decide what value to assign.

```
return results.Select(i =>
new Model
{
     Score = i.Score
     ,Date = i.InstanceResult.TestDate
     ,Category = categories.Any(c => c.Id.Equals(i.result.CategoryId)) ?
                 categories.First(c => c.Id.Equals(i.result.CategoryId)).Name : 
                 null
});
```

You could tidy this up with an extension method like so

```
...
Category = categories.GetNameFromId(i.result.CategoryId)
...

public static string GetNameFromId(this IEnumerable<Category> categories, string id)
{
    return categories.Any(c => c.Id.Equals(id)) ?
                 categories.First(c => c.Id.Equals(id)).Name : 
                 null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  use `FirstOrDefault` like this but you need to execute same query twice, if you want to do that in one statement:

```
Category = categories
           .FirstOrDefault(c=> c.Id.Equals(i.result.CategoryId)) != null ? 
           categories
           .FirstOrDefault(c=> c.Id.Equals(i.result.CategoryId)).Name : null;
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` returns `default(T)` if it can't find a matching element, which means you can do `Categories != null ? Category.Name : null` right away if it's a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

```
return results.Select(i =>
                {
                    var singleOrDefault = categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id.Equals(i.result.CategoryId));
                    return new Model
                        {
                            Score = i.Score,
                            Date = i.InstanceResult.TestDate,
                            Category = singleOrDefault != null ? singleOrDefault.Name : null
                        };
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
categories.Where(c=>c.Id.Equals(i.result.CategoryId)).SingleOrDefault()
```

returns null if nothing has been found. If you then try to access ".Name" it will throw an exception like you have got.

Try to make it that way:

```
Category singleCategory = categories.Where(c=>c.Id == i.result.CategoryId).SingleOrDefault();
if (singleCategory != null)
{
    // Do something with the Properties
}
```